# How do I change how the blender menu looks?

Tags: interface, customization

I am teaching an online class that uses Blender. Sometimes a student will turn in an assignment and it opens showing different menu choices. I'm not sure how it is happening and how to get back to the default menu choices.

[image: Screenshot showing both views of Blender menusBl]
I did not write this course and I am learning Blender along with the students. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

When you open a new file, go to File > Open. After this you will have a browser, select the file and look for the gear icon on the right top corner, click that and uncheck Load UI

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The menus adapt to changes the student has made, such as enabling an add-on; turning overlays on and off; creating or renaming a workspace. There are a few things you can do.

If you really want to set everything back to the default, go to the File menu, select Defaults->Load Factory Settings:

[image: factory reset]

Your example of Layout versus 3D View Full is probably because you and the student are using different releases of Blender.  You can partially alleviate this problem when you open the student's blend file.  Open it by using the File menu "Open" item.  In the dialog box, there is a hidden panel that you can open with the 'n' key:

[image: dialog box]

If you disable "Load UI" then you will get the interface that your used to, rather than the student's layout.

The second item you point out is an overlay.  You can change overlays in the overlay menu:

[image: overlays menu]

[image: overlays menu expanded]

You will see different overlays depending on what editor you are in and what mode the editor is in.